# Server Upload to presigned URL

Tags: file-upload, cloud-storage, amazon-s3, design-flaw, security-by-design

I am writing a ReST service which enables user to get a tar archive of a set of requested documents. When the request succeeds, the service should upload the file to a pre-signed URL that points to an s3 bucket or azure blob storage or a private minio server, or any other object store which the user specifies. This requires the rest endpoint to receive the signature info and the pre-signed URL from the user. So if I design the rest endpoint as a POST endpoint that receives a JSON object as input similar to below, the user can specify the signature parameters and URL to where the archive file should finally get uploaded to.

```
{
documentIds: [123, 456, 789],
uploadurl: "https://abcd.efgh.ln/prefix",
headers: {
  "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
  },
"formFields" : {
  "X-Amz-Algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256",
  "X-Amz-Expires":432000,
  "X-Amz-SignedHeaders": "host"
  "X-Amz-Signature": "afe0c52ca53a123bb2e2c038523966399396a4000ae99d2f29a7a212327e434",
  ...
  }
}
```

The service uses the form fields, headers, and the upload URL specified in the request to POST the output file to the remote object store.

However, as I see it, this design has serious security vulnerabilities, as this enables a user to make the service send a file and a set of form fields to any other server. Hence, how can we improve the design from a security standpoint?

Comment: Your problem of *"make the service send a file and a set of form fields to any other server"* is a direct consequence of your requirement *" or __any other__ object store which the user specifies"*.  Thus, either adjust the requirement of live with the consequences. There is no way to basically have a requirement of "allow arbitrary things" and then ask how to forbid to "do arbitrary things" while keeping the requirement.

Comment: Yes. That makes sense. Will try to use a whitelist